# Converting a hexadecimal string to a binary string using Rust pattern matching lookup

Tags: beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, rust, converting, number-systems

I am getting started in Rust, and as a part of my first exercise, I decided to write a small program that converts a hexadecimal string to a binary string using a pattern matched lookup. I would appreciate a constructive review.

```
fn main() {
    let binary_value = convert_to_binary_from_hex("0x39A7F8");
    println!("Converted: {}", binary_value);   
}

fn convert_to_binary_from_hex(hex: &str) -> String {
   let to_binary = hex[2 ..]
       .chars()
       .map(|c| to_binary(c))
       .collect();

   to_binary
} 

fn to_binary(c: char) -> String {
    let b = match c {
       '0' => "0000",
       '1' => "0001",
       '2' => "0010",
       '3' => "0011",
       '4' => "0100",
       '5' => "0101",
       '6' => "0110",
       '7' => "0111",
       '8' => "1000",
       '9' => "1001",
       'A' => "1010",
       'B' => "1011",
       'C' => "1100",
       'D' => "1101",
       'E' => "1110",
       'F' => "1111",
        _  => "",
    };

   b.to_string()
}
```

Comment: To be clear, you are *deliberately* not using relevant tools from the standard library, right?

Comment: @Shepmaster - Correct. I am trying to familiarize myself with the primitives of the language before leveraging the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt) is a tool for automatically formatting Rust code to the community-accepted style.
- [Clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy) is a tool for finding common mistakes that may not be compilation errors but are unlikely to be what the programmer intended.

Rustfmt points out that you are using 3-space indents (Rust uses 4), and that some of your lines don't need to be split.

Clippy points out:

```
warning: returning the result of a let binding from a block
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
7 |     let to_binary = hex[2..].chars().map(|c| to_binary(c)).collect();
  |     ----------------------------------------------------------------- unnecessary let binding
8 |
9 |     to_binary
  |     ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(clippy::let_and_return)] on by default
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#let_and_return
help: return the expression directly
  |
7 |
8 |
9 |     hex[2..].chars().map(|c| to_binary(c)).collect()
  |

warning: redundant closure found
 --> src/main.rs:7:42
  |
7 |     let to_binary = hex[2..].chars().map(|c| to_binary(c)).collect();
  |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: remove closure as shown: `to_binary`
  |
  = note: #[warn(clippy::redundant_closure)] on by default
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_closure
```

There's no reason to return a `String` here, a `&'static str` is lighter-weight. See [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24158114/155423) for full details, but a `String` requires a heap allocation, while a `&'static str` is a reference to some existing data in the compiled binary.

With these changes, all of your tests pass:

```
fn main() {
    let binary_value = convert_to_binary_from_hex("0x39A7F8");
    println!("Converted: {}", binary_value);
}

fn convert_to_binary_from_hex(hex: &str) -> String {
    hex[2..].chars().map(to_binary).collect()
}

fn to_binary(c: char) -> &'static str {
    match c {
        '0' => "0000",
        '1' => "0001",
        '2' => "0010",
        '3' => "0011",
        '4' => "0100",
        '5' => "0101",
        '6' => "0110",
        '7' => "0111",
        '8' => "1000",
        '9' => "1001",
        'A' => "1010",
        'B' => "1011",
        'C' => "1100",
        'D' => "1101",
        'E' => "1110",
        'F' => "1111",
        _ => "",
    }
}
```

In fact, deleting all of your code causes your tests to pass. It would be a good idea to add some tests!

Depending on what routes you want to look down next, you could try:

- to handle strings that do not start with `0x` without panicking.
- to handle upper- and lower-case hex
- to reduce/avoid string munging yourself

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. I will definitely use rustfmt and clippy from now on.You mentioned that returning &'static str is lighter weight than returning String, Could you please elaborate on that in your response?

Comment: @sc_ray: By returning a reference to the original string data (`&str`), you avoid an extra copy/allocation. The lifetime of the reference is `'static` in this case because it is referencing data within the program's binary, not a runtime `String`.